# Unable to find urlrewrite conf file at /WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am implementing URL Rewrite functionality and I have included all that is necessary for it in my project i.e. `urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` and `urlrewrite.xml` in WEB-INF and added the following in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
<filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But i am getting the following error,

> unable to find urlrewrite conf file at /WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

Please give me suggestions as to what can be done to solve this.

Comment: Would you like to post your conf file here?

Comment: Where can i find the conf file, is it from Jboss or from the source itself...?

Comment: source ofcourse, webapproot/web-inf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the conf file in params. This could be added to the filter conf.

> ```
> <!-- if you need to the conf file path can be changed
>     it is specified as a path relative to the root of your context
>     (default /WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml) -->
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>confPath</param-name>
>         <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> ```

Comment: @varsha could you post the absolute path to urlrewrite.xml?

Comment: Here is the path: /ProjectA/WebContent/WEB-INF/ urlrewrite.xml

Comment: @varsha your file has extra space in name beginning/ Rename the file and remove a space char.

Comment: Thank you @Roman, you were correct, there was mismatch in the file name and the path specified